# ampersand in URL of RSS Feed

Tags: asp.net

As part of our app, user can save some data as XML on server which becomes RSS feed for them.

Now some of the file user created have & in file name as BB&T_RSS.xml.

So when user point this to http://example.com/BB&T.xml, they won't get this.

How to stop this? I tried BB%26T.xml, BB&amp;T.xml without any success with IE, Chrome

Comment: BB%26T.xml should work as its been properly encoded.  Are these files just stored in the file system? Or is the server processing the filename first?

Comment: BB%26T.xml should work. Check the path make sure it is there.

Comment: XML files are just stored on file system(on Server) and user just type this URL in browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use an

```
%26
```

for an

&

http://example.com/BB%26T.xml,

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

then use

[HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx)

to get the file from the url again

> URL encoding ensures that all browsers will correctly transmit text in URL strings. Characters such as a question mark (?), ampersand (&), slash mark (/), and spaces might be truncated or corrupted by some browsers. As a result, these characters must be encoded in  tags or in query strings where the strings can be re-sent by a browser in a request string.
>
> Many URL schemes reserve certain characters for a special meaning:
>      their appearance in the scheme-specific part of the URL has a
>      designated semantics. If the character corresponding to an octet is
>      reserved in a scheme, the octet must be encoded.  The characters ";",
>      "/", "?", ":", "@", "=" and "&" are the characters which may be
>      reserved for special meaning within a scheme. No other characters may
>      be reserved within a scheme. ([src](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt))